# Angular call to NodeJS+Express for a basic GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, routes

I want to simply make a successful GET request to my NodeJS+Express server from an Angular component.

someComponent.ts

```
console.log("Before");
// send to server
console.log(this.http.get('/email').map((res:Response) => { 
  console.log("middle");
  return res; 
}));
console.log("After");
```

server.js

```
app.get('/email', function(req, res, next){
    res.send('GET email request');
});
```

Chrome console output:

```
Before
->t
   -> operator: t(thisArg: undefined, project: f)
   -> source: t {_isScalar: false, surce: t, operator t}
      _isScalar: false
   -> __proto__: Object
After
```

Can someone tell me if theres something wrong with this code? I don't think the callback function is executing because the console isn't outputting "middle". Also i dont know what kind of http response object this 't' is supposed to be in console. Shouldn't the correct console log be "GET email request" instead of this "t" object.

Answer (score 1):

Using the HttpModule in app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

and add to imports: [HttpModule]

You can simply type (in your component):

```
constructor(private http: Http){}
this.http.get('http://full_uri_endpoint:port/email').subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

Comment: The module is imported and injected into the component. For your http call and callback, i get "Before" "after" "null", not sure what thats supposed to indicate

Comment: I'm not sure where you 'get' the "Before" "after" "null". Could you show me what actually happens?

Comment: I mean that this is the console output, which should be log 
the response or error but instead returns null if i look at the console log here  http://i.imgur.com/gU7DBrH.png

Comment: Then your server doesn't return the value correctly. Maybe a header issue

Comment: It returns the same for an off-site URL like http://stackoverflow.com so im not sure :/